# How to calculate Resonance Frequency of Audio Speaker?

Tags: power, audio, frequency, speakers, resonance

Okay so I searched all over the Web for the resonance frequency of my car speaker so I can properly apply crossover filters, but didn't found any reference of the resonance frequency of this speaker model.

So how can I calculate it?

I have the following data:

Peak power: 150w
Rms power: 20w
Response Frequency: 90Hz-20kHz
Sensitivity: 91db/W/m
4 ohm

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: There are many resources online that detail this process (simply search "finding speaker resonant frequency"), but briefly: you can use a waveform generator and oscilloscope to measure voltage across the speaker as a function of frequency.

Comment: Disconnect Amp. apply 9V on off and record thump wave then analyze using Audacity >tools>spectrum analysis. That is it.  also if you don't know impedance, measure DCR and approximately double that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot **CALCULATE** *Fs*, (Resonant frequency of loudspeaker moving mass in free air).  But you can **MEASURE** it relatively easily.  You will need a power amp, a variable frequency source, and a DMM.  THere are many resources online for measuring driver characteristics. Fs is one of the primary measurements for the popular Thiele/Small parameters.  Here is one straightforward explanation:

Ref: https://sound-au.com/tsp.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually that's too hard for me lol. I will instead contact the manufacturer and ask them about the speaker Fs :)

Comment: I though there was a simple math that could give me Fs. Thank you very much!

Comment: To be fair @RichardCrowley: I'm sure you *can* calculate Fs, it's just much easier to measure it.